# Estimating a "transition" matrix from data

Tags: linear-algebra

I have observation vectors $X_1$, $X_2$, $X_3$, and so on.

I assume that there is a matrix A such that $AX_n = X_{n+1}$.

How do I calculate A?

I'm sure this is a standard problem but I don't know what to search for in Google...

Comment: Perhaps vector autoregression (VAR) models are what you are looking for.

Comment: That answers my question.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

[Vector Autoregression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_autoregression) (VAR) is possibly what you are looking for. Usually there is a zero-mean error term so that your expression holds in expectation.